# SQL Join based on hierarchical criteria

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables that I require to be intrajoined to form a third table.

The first table (Basic) looks like this:

```
+----------+----------+---------+------------+
| Order No | Supplier | Product |    Date    |
+----------+----------+---------+------------+
|      100 | SuppCo   | Shirt   | 25.09.2014 |
|      101 | SuppCo   | Pants   | 25.09.2014 |
|      102 | SuppCo   | Shirt   | 25.09.2014 |
+----------+----------+---------+------------+
```

The second table (Color) looks like this:

```
+------+--------+
|  ID  | Color  |
+------+--------+
| 1ABC | yellow |
| 1ABD | red    |
| 1ABE | pink   |
| 1ABF | orange |
| 1ABG | teal   |
| 2DEG | green  |
| 3HIK | blue   |
+------+--------+
```

The third table (Detail) looks like this:

```
+------+----------+-----------+
|  ID  | Order No | Order Ext |
+------+----------+-----------+
| 1ABC |      100 | -         |
| 1ABD |      100 | Prime     |
| 1ABE |      100 | Basic1    |
| 1ABF |      100 | Basic2    |
| 1ABG |      100 | Basic3    |
+------+----------+-----------+
```

The final table should look like this:

```
+----------+------+-------+------------+
| Order No |  ID  | Color |    Date    |
+----------+------+-------+------------+
|      100 | 1ABD | red   | 25.09.2014 |
|      101 | 2DEG | green | 25.09.2014 |
|      102 | 3HIK | blue  | 25.09.2014 |
+----------+------+-------+------------+
```

The table is based on the `Basic` table, where I use Order No and Date.
From the order number, I want to get the ID from the `Detail` table.

The join between `Basic` and `Detail` should have the following criteria:
Join the same order number and get the ID where `Order Ext = 'Prime'`, if Prime does not exist as an extension, then `Order Ext = '-'` and if that does not exist, then take any of the rest (it does not matter at this point).
After this, the ID should be taken and get the right row from the `Color` table.

I was thinking about Row Over but that is quite resource draining, so I was thinking if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more column in Detail, where you can give Priority to row with this ID.
And then you can use this SELECT:

```
SELECT B.Order_No, C.ID, C.Color, B.Date
FROM [Basic] B
INNER JOIN Detail D ON B.Order_No = D.Order_No 
    AND D.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 D1.ID 
                FROM Detail D1
                WHERE D1.Order_No = B.Order_No
                ORDER BY D1.OrderPriority ASC)
INNER JOIN Color C ON C.ID = D.ID
```